# Find and Replace Text with Empty Values

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Dears, in one of my input file the text is like as below.

```
(LOCKED) (DISABLED) RncFunction=1,UtranCell=UE1146XB3 
(LOCKED) (DISABLED) RncFunction=1,UtranCell=UE1146XC3 
(LOCKED) (DISABLED) RncFunction=1,UtranCell=UE1146XA0 
(LOCKED) (DISABLED) RncFunction=1,UtranCell=UE1146XB0 
(LOCKED) (DISABLED) RncFunction=1,UtranCell=UE1146XC0
```

Now I want the output as below by removing "RncFunction=1,UtranCell=" from each line.

```
(LOCKED) (DISABLED) UE1146XB3 
(LOCKED) (DISABLED) UE1146XC3 
(LOCKED) (DISABLED) UE1146XA0 
(LOCKED) (DISABLED) UE1146XB0 
(LOCKED) (DISABLED) UE1146XC0
```

I was using following code

```
cat input.log | sed 's\/RncFunction\ \g'
```

But it was not working. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: Do not use backslashes ` \\` here.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please use CODE TAGS for your sample inputs and sample outputs, commands/scripts as per forum rules, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This replaces `Rnc` and all the following, including the last `=`, with nothing.

```
sed 's/Rnc.*=//' input.log
```

Comment: Your command will work for single line. Below code will work for all occurrences. 
sed 's/Rnc.*=//g' input.log

Comment: @SajibIslam that's not true. You misunderstand how sed works and what `g` at the end means. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` and `sed` solutions may help you too.

***Solution 1st:*** using `sed`'s capability of keeping matched regex into memory.

```
sed 's/\([^(RncFunction)]*\)\(RncFunction.*=\)\(.*\)/\1\3/'   Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd***: Using `awk`'s out of the box utility called `sub` which will substitute the strings as per their provided regex.

```
awk '{sub(/RncFunction.*=/,"")} 1'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Just substitute the unwanted string with nothing:

```
$ cat /tmp/tmp.txt | sed 's/RncFunction=1,UtranCell=//'
(LOCKED) (DISABLED) UE1146XB3
(LOCKED) (DISABLED) UE1146XC3
(LOCKED) (DISABLED) UE1146XA0
(LOCKED) (DISABLED) UE1146XB0
(LOCKED) (DISABLED) UE1146XC0

$ cat /tmp/tmp.txt
(LOCKED) (DISABLED) RncFunction=1,UtranCell=UE1146XB3
(LOCKED) (DISABLED) RncFunction=1,UtranCell=UE1146XC3
(LOCKED) (DISABLED) RncFunction=1,UtranCell=UE1146XA0
(LOCKED) (DISABLED) RncFunction=1,UtranCell=UE1146XB0
(LOCKED) (DISABLED) RncFunction=1,UtranCell=UE1146XC0
```